# DXA 2.2 site.log ERROR - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

update
DXA site 2.2 with Tridion 9.1, CD discovery content context gets correct health state. 
this is on Azure App Service with CM and CDs on VM

```
2020-05-26 17:16:45,857 [78] ERROR - System.InvalidCastException:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String[]]'. 
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.ClaimStore.ClaimStore.Get[T](Uri claimUri) 
at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_IsSessionPreview() in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 151 
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization) 
in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 192 
at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 134

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String[]]'. 
at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.ClaimStore.ClaimStore.Get[T](Uri claimUri)  
at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_IsSessionPreview() 
in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 151 
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization) 
in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 192 
at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
in C:\SDL\sample\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 134
```

Comment: this is a volunteer based forum. If you're too lazy to type the question and provide the context, why should people put in effort to try and look at your exception without any context.

Comment: this is dxa site log with tridion 9.1 got this error. CD discovery, content, context all get health correctly.

Comment: Follow this for "How do I ask a good question?" https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the claim store configuration and comment it out.

Comment: thanks Chris :) all the best

Comment: BTW, not sure why AmbientFrameworkModule not working on the website anything missing in CDs?

Comment: I remember a similar issue in a previous upgrade some years ago, Ambient framework needed some configuration for UGC if I remember correctly. I was not using UGC so just commented out AF to solve the problem. Checkout SDL docs "Adding the Ambient Data Framework client to a .NET Web application"

Comment: i found out we don't use UGC :)

Comment: You also need ADF for XPM Session Preview, eXperience Optimization and Audience Manager. But if you’re not using any of those, it’s best to remove the ADF Module, indeed (it has significant performance overhead too).

Comment: thanks Rick, this very helpful